# having php indent properly on echo?

Tags: php, html

I recently created a new login-register system for myself but i'm having issues with htmls indenting when echoed from php, Now that i've really looked at it, i realized that echoing a entire page isnt the smartest idea, unless it is?

```
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['sessionId'])) {
    echo('This is the new content after login.');
} else{
    echo 'This is the login page';
}

?>
```

above is my index.php the first echo would echo the entire page of content the user would see after they logged in.

Second is the login form.

what would be the easiest way to go about this?

Comment: The best way is to use a PHP framework with an MVC strucutre (model, view, controller) - this allows you to write all of your HTML in plain HTML and keep all of the PHP separate.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to indent? Your code doesn't have HTML tags or line feeds :-? In web sites you build a layout with HTML, CSS and pictures. Can you please edit the question and clarify that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['sessionId'])) {
    readfile("/path/to/html/file/new_content.html");
} else{
    readfile("/path/to/html/file/login.html");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try echoing your HTML output like so

```
<?php

    if (isset($_SESSION['sessionId'])) {
    echo '<br><p>';
    echo'This is the new content after login.';
    echo '</p>';
    } else{
    echo '<br><p>';
    echo '  This is the login page';
    echo '</p>';
    }

    ?>
```

You'll see the above code in view source if you use it
Output:

```html
<br>
<p>
&nbsp&nbspThis is the content after login
</p>
second output
<br>
<p>
&nbsp&nbspThis is the login page
</p>
```

P.S. BTW why are you using brackets for one echo and none for the other 
???